# Backbone + jquery + Java rest backend error callback on model.save()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, resteasy, jboss7.x

I am developing a web application using backbonejs v 0.5.3 + jquery v 1.6.4.
On the backend side I use jboss rest easy on jboss AS 7.0.2.

When I try to fetch a model everything works well but when I try to update a model the error callback function is called every time. Here is my js code:

```
save : function() {
    this.model.save({id : this.model.get('id')}, {
        success : function(model, resp) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error : function(model, resp) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
},
```

The strange thing is: if I try to debug the javascript code the success alert is shown. In normal executions the error alert is displayed (I got the same behavior on Chrome and Firefox).

Any thought on this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your service returning on the POST/PUT save operations?

Make sure that the server is returning the JSON representation of your object in the body... or at least a JSON representation of the fields that changed. Especially make sure the ID field is sent back as Backbone will use it later when updating or deleting.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for getting back to me. My service is returning back the json representation of the updated object after the PUT invocation. I think I have a different problem. I have added a sleep  invocation of 20 secs on my service code and I re-execute the code. I expect to see the error alert after 20 secs. Instead, the error callback executes immediately after the model.save() call. It does not wait for the service response at all! Any idea on this? Thanks

Comment: Time to start debugging the un-minified source :)  Are you getting any exceptions in the console log?  What does the `resp` object look like?

Comment: I don't see any exception in the console log. Here is the response object:  **Status:** 200 OK  **Headers:** Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2011 20:22:09 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json  **Data:** {"@type":"d","@rid":"#11:0","@version":"1","id":"myemail@email.com","firstname":"Name","lastname":"Surname","creationdate":"2011-11-02 21:16:48:317","out":"#6:0"}

Comment: And when you put a breakpoint inside the internal [success](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41) and [error[(http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-145) callbacks, can you step through and learn something?  Does Backbone receive an error from `$.ajax` or is the error on the `parse` or `set` calls for an internal success?

Comment: I can step through the wrapError backbone function but responseText and statusText are empty. status value is 0. I cannot see any error from jquery ajax call.

Comment: Problem solved: the save function is bound to a form submit event. To sort it out I just added `onsubmit="return false"` to the form tag. In this way the save call works fine! Brian, thanks for the support!